# use regex to test string match with only accept 1 and dot but 11 not acceptable

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to set a regex test to test the string is 1.1 or 1.1.1 or 1.1.1.1 etc
but I only know this only accept 1 and .

```
/^[1\.]+$/.test(string)
```

If I test 1.11.1, it still return true.

Comment: try this `^(?:1\.)+[1.]$`

Comment: @VishalSingh Your regex would also match `1..`, [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzBVyo/1)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If it's certain that the string is going to end with `1` then `[1.]` can be replaced with `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `^1(?:\.1)*$`:

```js
var input = ["1", "1.1", "1.1.1.1", "1.2.3.4", "1.11", "hot dog"];
for (var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (/^1(?:\.1)*$/.test(input[i])) {
        result = "MATCH";
    }
    else { 
        result = "NO MATCH";
    }
    console.log(input[i] + " => " + result);
}
```

Comment: it is not work. If I run /1(?:\.1)*/.test('1.11.1'), It still return true.

Comment: @KennethChan Please check my updated answer which contains more examples.

Answer (score 3):

If the string only accepts zero and one, but can not contain `11` you can use a negative look ahead to assert not `11`.

Note that you don't have to escape the `.` in the character class.

```
^(?!.*11)[.1]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5A003s/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*11)[.1]+$/;
[
  "1.1",
  "1.1.1",
  "1.1.1.1",
  "...",
  "..1111",
  "1.1.....",
  "...1..1.."
].forEach(s => {
  const m = regex.test(s);
  if (m) {
    console.log(`Match -->  ${s}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`No match --> ${s}`);
  }
})
```

If there should be at least a `.` and a `1` present, you can add asserting a `.` and match at least a 1

```
^(?!.*11)(?=1*\.)[.]*1[.1]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZlaXO/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*11)(?=1*\.)[.]*1[.1]*$/;
[
  "1.1",
  "1.1.1",
  "1.1.1.1",
  "...",
  "..1111",
  "1.1.....",
  "...1..1.."
].forEach(s => {
  const m = regex.test(s);
  if (m) {
    console.log(`Match -->  ${s}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`No match --> ${s}`);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^(?:1\.)+[1]$|^(1)$
```

if you do not want to match `1` by itself

```
^(?:1\.)+[1]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you might want to think about using here is to build a DFA. Since the regex is so simple, it does not take much effort:

```js
function check(a){
  let isChecked = true;
  let STATE = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if(STATE === 0 && a[i] === '1') STATE = 1;  
        else if(STATE === 1 && a[i] === '.') STATE = 0;
        else{ isChecked = false; }
    }
  if(STATE === 0) isChecked = false;
    return isChecked;
}

let arr = ['1', '1.11.1', '1.1.1.1', 'a.vad.bsadf.1', '1.1.111.1']
arr.forEach((a) => console.log(check(a)))
```